# Conjunction after verb in dictionary form

Tags: conjunctions

How exactly do you say "but" when it's an information situation and the fist sentence is in plain form?
In formal speech it would be something like this:

> 漢字が読めます**が**、漢字が書けません。

In informal speech, what would the **が** become? *(Without using でも)*

> 漢字が読める＿＿、漢字が書けない。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use が even if it does not follow マス形. That said

> 漢字が読めるが、漢字が書けない。

is grammatical.

There are some alternatives けど<けれど<けども<けれども (least to most formal):

> 漢字が読めるけど、漢字が書けない。
>   漢字が読めるけども、漢字が書けない。
>   漢字が読めるけれども、漢字が書けない。